# Angular 5 - Highcharts cannot load data from a HTML table

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular5

I am trying to create a highchart pie from htmltable but its not getting created
i have installed highchart from [this url](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-highcharts-with-angular-5-6c6564a55cf0) . With series data highchart is working well. but as soon as i tried to pick the data from html table. Its not getting formed.i have also tried with removing display none of html table but still it wont work. please suggest what to do in this case.

below is template code :

```
  <div class="highcart_div" #highcart_div style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
        <table id="datatable" #datatable style="display: none;">

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Apples</th>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Pears</th>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Plums</th>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Bananas</th>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Oranges</th>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Below is component code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { chart } from "highcharts";
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-analytics-content',
  templateUrl: './analytics-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analytics-content.component.css']
})
export class AnalyticsContentComponent implements OnInit {
  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;
  @ViewChild("highcart_div") chartTarget: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("datatable") datatable: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
      data: {
        table: this.datatable.nativeElement

      },

      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: 'Units'
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          innerSize: '60%'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return '<b>'
            + this.series.name
            + '</b><br/>'
            + this.point.y
            + ' '
            + this.point.name
              .toLowerCase();
        }
      }
    };
    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, options);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check official [npm highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts), import the dependency in angular component

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-extracted-from-a-html-table?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) demo

app.component.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as  Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
// Initialize exporting module.
Exporting(Highcharts);
import Data from 'highcharts/modules/data';
// Initialize Data module.
Data(Highcharts);
import ExportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
// Initialize ExportData module.
ExportData(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
  @ViewChild("container", { read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("datatable", { read: ElementRef }) datatable: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    Highcharts.chart(this.container.nativeElement, {
      data: {
        table: this.datatable.nativeElement
      },
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
      },
      yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: 'Units'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: how to Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting', data

Comment: how to export it i have installled highchart from mentioned url given in the answer but getting compilation exception in this line "import ExportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
"